# How to pass parameters to Python function as pointer using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

In Python by pointer are passed: `list`, `tuple` and etc. Can i pass simple variables by pointer using ctypes module?

Comment: Must you use `ctypes`? If not, see the last part of the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I just started to deal with `ctypes` module and thought it was cool, if i could pass the variables by pointer in Python functions too.

Comment: What do you mean? All variables in Python have the same exact call semantics. There is not distinction between "simple" variables and others. They work the same.

Comment: I mean that i can change values  of list via function like pointer in C++, but it is not work with simple variables.

Comment: @ИванСушков: That doesn't really have to do with pointers.  It has to do with the fact that list objects make available certain operations (like `append`) that mutate the object.  When you get an int, you also have a "pointer" to it, but you can't mutate it because the int object doesn't have any methods that would allow you to do so.